# Samba file locking and sharing has stopped working

Tags: samba, libreoffice, file-sharing

I am running a small office network on an Ubuntu server 18.04 with Samba. Most of the regular computers are Ubuntu, with one 14.04, one 16.04,  four Linux Mint 18.04. There are two Win 10 computers and one apple, hence the need for Samba. We also use Libreoffice extensively, particularly Calc and Write. This setup has been running for years, mostly problem free.

Recently, I noticed a problem with file locking. Previously, if a file was in use, the second user would be able to open the file read-only, or a copy of the file. Now, the second user sees a message that the file is coruupt and Libreoffice will attempt to recover the file. So the second user is unable to view the file. Since there are three layers involved, Ubuntu, Libreoffice or Samba I don't know where the problem lies.

This is not an urgent issue, as we are able to continue operating.  Still, it is irritating, and web research up to this point has not yielded any good clues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here, have you found a solution or a bug/issue in any of the projects? 

I believe it also has to do with the lock file itself, as I had dangling old logfiles (probably after some crash or network hickup) where I could still see the dialog and open the file just fine. Unfortunately I canot replicate it (the gicen lockfile is gone now and my memory might trick me anyway).